# Google Report list api is throwing 500

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-audit-api

Google Admin report list api suddenly started throwing 500.
Have tried from api as well as from SDK and both are throwing GoogleJsonResponseException.
after debugging found that if we don't specify eventName filter then it is working but after adding evenName filter (ex.download or edit) it throws 500.
API : https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all

Try above api from google itself via https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list

and specify any eventName(view,edit,download,share)

below is SDK code

```
Reports.Activities.List list = Reports.activities().list(caller, activityName).setOauthToken("accesstoken").setMaxResults("1000") .setStartTime(startTime).setStartTime("endTime").setEventName("edit"); 
Activities result = list.execute();
```

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all

Try above api from google itself via https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list

and specify any eventName(view,edit,download,share)

Comment: Im not the one having the error.   I need to see your code, how are you authorizing the request?

Comment: Reports.Activities.List list = Reports.activities().list(caller, activityName)
      .setOauthToken("accesstoken")
      .setMaxResults("1000")
      .setStartTime(startTime)
                        .setStartTime("endTime")
                        .setEventName("edit");

Activities result = list.execute();

Comment: authorizing with oauth2 token

Comment: Please **edit** your question and include your code.  a [example]  What is that java?

Comment: started working fine before 30 mins, for same request API is giving results.looks like it is fixed from google side.

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted the error message here, but usually Error 500 most of the time refer to a `backend error` and google remedy is to implement exponential backoff.

From your post is quite unclear is that for a specific user or all of them, but the error message from Google are quite reasonable and will give you a good guidance, so expand that JSON resonse `GoogleJsonResponseException`